# OCI runtime create failed Cannot start service tomcat: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed Docker Container-TOMCAT

Tags: linux, docker, tomcat, docker-compose, tomcat9

Does anyone know why when creating a path to /usr/local/tomcat in volumes it gives me this error?

```
Cannot start service tomcat: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create   failed: unable to start container process: exec:"catalina.sh" executeable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

If I change volumes to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps it works.
My Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
service:
 tomcat: 
  image: tomcat:9.0
  restart: always
  depends_on:
   - db
  ports: 
   - 8080:8080
  volumes:
   - /usr/local/docker/tomcat:/usr/local/tomcat   
  environment:
   CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
   CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
   CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
   JRE_HOME:        /usr
   CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat- juli.jar
 db:
  image: mysql 
   restart: always
   volmues: 
     - /var/lib/mysql/data
   ports:
     - 3306:3306
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
     MYSQL_DATABASE: example
```